# Reduce an array to groups

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
const vals = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green']
```

I would like to reduce it to this:

```
['blueblue', 'green', 'blue', 'yellowyellow', 'green']
```

Where it concats the values if they are the same. Once the value changes it starts again.

Trying to use reduce but not sure how to make it work as the `acc` needs to be a string and an array depending on if the value is the same or not!

```
let lastType = vals[0]
const groups = vals.reduce((acc, value) => {
  if (lastType === value) {
    acc += value // string
  }

  lastType = value
  return acc.push(value)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final result is an array, so that is what `acc` should be.

Instead of appending `value` to `acc`, append it to the last element of the array:

```js
const vals = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green']

let lastType = null;

const groups = vals.reduce((acc, value) => {
  if (lastType === value) {
    acc[acc.length - 1] += value;
  } else {
    lastType = value
    acc.push(value)
  }

  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(groups);
```

The use of `lastType` in a closure is a bit of a code smell, as is the use of mutability in the reducer.

A preferable, though slightly more verbose approach:

```js
const vals = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green']

const { groups } = vals.reduce(({ lastType, groups }, value) => {
  if (lastType === value) {
    return {
        lastType,
        groups: [
          ...groups.slice(0, groups.length - 2),
          groups[groups.length - 1] + value
        ],
    };
  }

  return {
    lastType: value,
    groups: [...groups, value],
  };
}, { groups: [], lastType: null })

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: simpler than mine, nice

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the element at the index in front of the actual index and add a new string to the accumulator.

```js
const
    values = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green'],
    result = values.reduce((accumulator, value, index, array) => {
        if (value === array[index - 1]) accumulator[accumulator.length - 1] += value;
        else accumulator.push(value);
        return accumulator;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Push an empty string to the accumulator if the type is new. Remember that `.push` returns the new length of the array, so don't return it at the bottom of the function - instead, return the whole accumulator:

```js
const vals = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green']
let lastType;
const groups = vals.reduce((acc, value) => {
  if (lastType !== value) {
    acc.push('');
    lastType = value;
  }
  acc[acc.length - 1] += value;
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of a bit more. Basic way of doing it is using an bject to hold the state.

```js
const vals = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'green']

const groups = vals.reduce((acc, value, index, array) => {
  // is it the same, duplicate it
  if (acc.lastType === value) {
    acc.current += value;
  } else {
     // did we have a previous value? Add it to the array
     if (acc.lastType) {
       acc.result.push(acc.current);
     }
     // set the current type
     acc.current = value;
     acc.lastType = value;
  }
  // if we are at the end, add what we have to the array
  if (index+1===array.length) {
    acc.result.push(acc.current);
  }
  
  return acc;

}, { result: [], current: '', lastType: null }).result;

console.log(groups);
```